# Eye strain from playing online chess

Tags: online-chess

How do you avoid eye strain while playing online chess? I wear glasses that filters UV light, take a 5-minute break every hour, play on a large screen monitor (23 inch with a refresh rate of 60 Hz), and use lubricant eye drops twice a day. But I also believe that one of the big factor is that I don't blink enough while playing chess. My eyes are most of the time wide open, in order to avoid blundering. I would really appreciate your feedback, advice, and experiences to avoid such kind of problems.

Comment: I think green/white chess boards are supposed to be easier to stare at ( https://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-equipment/what-boardpiece-colors-do-you-prefer ), but I don't know if that applies to online games.

Comment: Have you tried a blue light filter?

Comment: you mean an application like flux, yes I also have it installed on my laptop to filter blue light (high frequency waves)

Comment: How long are your games?

Comment: @Acccumulation I usually play for like 2 hours. The time controls that I play usually are: 3+2, 5, 5+3, 10, 10+3, and 15+5

Comment: So if you're playing 10+3, I take it a single a game isn't taking 2 hours? So that means you're playing several games in a session, your sessions take 2 hours, and halfway through you take a five minute break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 has a setting called "Night Light" in the display settings, and Mac has Night Shift which helps me with eye-strain by reducing blue-light that can cause eye-strain. You can also try the 20-20-20 technique instead of taking a 5 minute break every hour. My eye doctor suggested staring at something 20 feet away, for 20 seconds, every 20 minutes. Probably hard to do when you're playing a lot of blitz games, but something to consider. Good luck.

Comment: which one is better in your opinion: flux or Night Shift on Mac?

Comment: @Guess601 I've never tested 1 to 1, I didn't install flux as it was already a feature in MacOS by the time I started using it. Flux makes it a bit easier to switch on and off, since it has it's own UI.

Answer (score 3):

Using Eye Drops (fake tears) can be useful when exceeding recommended screen time.

What also helps me is taking frequent breaks every hour and drinking plenty of water.

Comment: what's the recommended screen time per day?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to look away from the screen every 15 minutes. It reduces stress on your eyes and you can concentrate better when you return to the game.